# If I copy text from PDF and paste using ckeditor, double quotes becomes a dash. Why is a character changed?

Tags: php, ckeditor

This is the original PDF text:

> H. Xu and B. Li, "Efficient resource allocation with flexible channel
>   cooperation in OFDMA cognitive radio networks,‖ in Proc. IEEE INFOCOM,
>   2010.

This is the ckeditor paste text:

> H. Xu and B. Li, ―Efficient resource allocation with flexible channel
>   cooperation in OFDMA cognitive radio networks,‖ in Proc. IEEE INFOCOM,
>   2010.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF character is interpreted by ckeditor. Set

```
forcePasteAsPlainText
```

to

```
true
```

to disable the Advanced Content Filter